# Jquery Ajax popup form not sending data

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, popup

I have a pop form which does not seem to send the on submit data to jquery. What am i doing wrong?
The script to create the popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({
            html: true,
            title: function() {
                return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
            },
            content: function() {
                return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The form which is populated in popup

```
<div class="popover-markup"> 
    <a href="#" class="trigger btn btn-success">Add Your Genre</a> 
    <div class="head hide">Add Genre</div>
    <div class="content hide">
        <form method="post" action="" id="genreupdate">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <?php foreach($allgenres as $key=>$value) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                        <?php echo $value;?>
                    </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="footer hide">test</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY to send data to table

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("genreupdate").submit(function(e) {
            var genreid = $('#genreupdate').val();
            alert(genreid);
            var user = <? php echo AuthComponent::user('id'); ?> ;
            var targeturl = 'http://www.website/users/update';
            //alert(targeturl);
            .popover-markup('destroy');
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "html",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    genre_id: genreid,
                    user_id: user
                },
                evalScripts: true,
                url: targeturl,
                success: function() {
                    // Handle the complete event
                    var result = "Thanks for updating your fans";
                    $("#genreupdated").fadeOut(2000).html(result);
                    $(".genreid").val('');
                    document.location.reload();
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

I click on submit nothing happens.

Comment: I think you forgot '#' in the selector for the submit. It should look like this $("#genreupdate").submit(...); :)

Comment: Martin, thank you. Good observation. However, this did not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Few problems in the script, I'm not sure whether it fix your problem or not but possible errors with syntax will get resolved with it!

1. Correct id selector `$("genreupdate")` to `$("#genreupdate")`
2. For dynamic content we should use [`delegated events`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) will help you to pass the event from document to descendant selector.
3. Line `$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover('destroy');` corrected and moved to done method.
4. Your HTML not well formed, I've removed extra div closing and updated it in Qn.

**Script:**

```
  $(function () {
      $(document).on('submit',".popover form#genreupdate",function (e) {
          var genreid = $('#genreupdate').val(),
              user = <? php echo AuthComponent::user('id'); ?> ,
              targeturl = 'http://www.website/users/update';

          $.ajax({
              url: targeturl,
              dataType: "html",
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                  genre_id: genreid,
                  user_id: user
              },
              evalScripts: true
          }).done(function () {
              // Handle the complete event
              var result = "Thanks for updating your fans";
              $("#genreupdated").fadeOut(2000).html(result);
              $(".genreid").val('');
              document.location.reload();
             $('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover('destroy');
          });
      });
  });
```

Note: Where is the element with id = `genreupdated`

Comment: Venkata, good corrections. However, nothings happens. When i try it in a none popup box, it works. Why will it not work in a popup? I really need it to work in the popup

Comment: I updated answer with delegated event binding. Please try now

Comment: are you using dismiss on focus in popover?

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
$('#genreupdate') => $(".popover-content #genreupdate")
```

Like:

```
 $(".popover-content #genreupdate").submit(....);
```

And all places that you use:

```
$('#genreupdate')
```